# How to remove keyboard layout?

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, language-support

Running Ubuntu 18.04.3.

System Settings > Language and Region

I added an additional Input Source (keyboard layout in a different language).

How do I now remove that additional Input Source?

I feel like I'm missing something very obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Select the entry you want to delete and use the `-` sign below the `Input Sources` as seen in the screenshot below

[image]